# MaterialUI Appbar with Tabs - can it be scrollable AND fullwidth

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like my tab buttons to spread out across the entire screen.

When the screen width is too skinny to fit all the tabs, I would like the scroll buttons to show up.

MaterialUI has `variant='scrollable'` and the `variant='fullWidth'`.  It does not appear to allow both of these to be used at the same time.

If I use the property `scrollButtons='auto'` in combination with `variant='fullWidth'` I don't get scroll buttons when things get to skinny.

Is there a mechanism for letting this work?  Centering the buttons mitigates the issue somewhat, but isn't the real answer.

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/13610
Not intended to be supported out the box, so you will have to follow some kind of hack.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question has been asked a while ago but in case someone would wonder, here is what I did:

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from '@mui/material'

<Tabs {...propsTabs} variant="scrollable">
  <Tab {...propsTab1} sx={{ minWidth: "fit-content", flex: 1 }} />
  <Tab {...propsTab2} sx={{ minWidth: "fit-content", flex: 1 }} />
  {/*...*/}
</Tabs>
```

The MUI Tabs component has a `{ display: "flex" }` property.